# Odoo hide "Create" and "Edit" buttons depend on state and role

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9, formview

I would like to hide "Create" and "Edit" buttons on state and group role in **form view** .`For example hide Create and Edit buttons when the state is not draft and user belongs to request user group.`

As I understand hide buttons I can on editing views. And on group role rules I can disable create or edit.

I tried to `write a rule for request user group` but then user `can't use` the button `but see` it.

From view I found only way to hide default Create and Edit buttons:

```
<form string="Request" create="false" edit="false">
```

But in that way I hide them for all users for all states. Is there another way how can I hide Create and Edit buttons depend on `state` and `group role`?

I tried to expand the base.xml template on conditions state is "approved" or "done" and the group role is purchase_request_user and view id is view_purchase_request_form "Create" and "Edit" button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates xml:space='preserve'>
    <t t-extend="FormView.buttons">
        <t t-if="widget.fields_view.state !== 'done' or widget.fields_view.state !== 'approved'">
        <div class="o_form_buttons_view">
            <button t-if="widget.is_action_enabled('edit')"
                    type="button"
                    class="oe_form_button_edit btn btn-default btn-sm" accesskey="E">
                Edit
            </button>
            <button t-if="widget.is_action_enabled('create')"
                    type="button" class="oe_form_button_create btn btn-default btn-sm"
                    accesskey="C">
                Create
            </button>
        </div>
        </t>
    </t>
</templates>
```

added 'base' to dependences.

**UPDATED base.xml** Now I can change "Create" button name depend on my view name but nothing that depends on my module states.

```
<templates>
<t t-extend="FormView.buttons">
    <t t-jquery="button.oe_form_button_create" t-operation="replace">
        <t t-if="widget.fields_view.name == 'purchase.request.form'">
            <button t-if="widget.is_action_enabled('create')"
                    type="button" class="oe_form_button_create btn btn-default btn-sm"
                    accesskey="C">
                New button name
            </button>
        </t>
    </t>
 </t>
</templates>
```

My form view xml peace:

```
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_purchase_request_form">
            <field name="name">purchase.request.form</field>
            <field name="model">purchase.request</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Purchase Request" create="false" edit="false">
                <header>
                    <button name="%(action_sale_order_reset)d" attrs="{'invisible': [('state','not in', ('to_approve_first'))]}" string="Reset" type="action" groups="purchase_request.group_purchase_request_manager"/>
                    <button name="button_to_approve_first" states="draft" string="Request approval" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
                    <button name="button_approved" states="to_approve_first" string="Approve" type="object" class="oe_highlight" groups="purchase_request.group_purchase_request_manager"/>
                    <button name="button_approvedd" states="approved" string="Return Request" type="object" class="oe_highlight" groups="purchase_request.group_purchase_request_manager"/>
                    <button name="button_create_order" states="approvedd" string="Create Order" type="object" class="oe_highlight" groups="purchase_request.group_purchase_request_user"/>
                    <button name="button_to_approve_second" states="create_order" string="Approve" type="object" class="oe_highlight" groups="purchase_request.group_purchase_request_manager"/>
                    <button name="button_approved2" states="to_approve_second" string="Done" type="object" class="oe_highlight" groups="purchase_request.group_purchase_request_manager"/>
                    <button name="button_rejected" states="draft,approvedd" string="Reject" type="object" groups="purchase_request.group_purchase_request_user"/>
                    <field name="state" widget="statusbar" statusbar_visible="draft,to_approve_first,approved,rejected" statusbar_colors="{&quot;approved&quot;:&quot;green&quot;}"/>
                </header>
                <sheet>
                    <group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="date_start" readonly="1"/>
                            <field name="participate_process"/>
                        </group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="requested_by" readonly="1"/>
                            <field name="assigned_to" attrs="{'readonly': [('state','not in', ('draft'))]}" />
                        </group>
                  <notebook>
                        <page string="Order" attrs="{'invisible': [('state','in', ('draft', 'to_approve_first', 'approved', 'approvedd'))]}">
                            <field name="supply_ids" attrs="{'readonly': [('state','not in', ('to_approve_second'))]}"/>
                        </page>
                   </notebook>
                </sheet>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a template inheriting the *'FormView.buttons'* one, check the context fields, like groups and state, and put a condition based on the wanted fields.

Something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates xml:space='preserve'>
    <t t-extend="FormView.buttons">
        <t t-if="widget.fields_view.state == <wanted_state>">
            <your operations>
        </t>
    </t>
</templates>
```

Comment: So if I want that when the state is "approved" or "done" and the group role is purchase_request_user and view id is view_purchase_request_form "Create" and "Edit" buttons will be hiddenI tried to expand existing base.xml template but something is wrong. I edited my question.

Comment: Add a control on the view name. Something like *<t t-if="widget.fields_view.name == 'res.partner.form'">*.
Then I would do a control when you want to hide the buttons and replace their div with nothing instead redesign them.
Like: *<t t-jquery='<your control>' t-operation='replace'/>*

Comment: Sorry, I meant *'<your selector>'* in *t-jquery*.

Comment: Can you edit your answer by the lasts comments? I'm going to try. But still don't understand till the end..

Comment: Just for check I tried to change core base.xml, so with <you operation> everything was ok, but with this statement: t-if="widget.fields_view.state == <wanted_state>" something wrong. The problem is that <wanted_state> is not set or core can't see my view states.

Comment: Sorry I was a little busy. Anyway try to set a *<t t-log='widget'/>* to check the context you have. It simply will be the *'FormView'* widget one. If you want to check the widget itself you find it in *addons/web/static/src/js/views/form_view.js*. So you can understand it by yourself. Otherwise I'll help you, don't worry.

Comment: Hello, I found that when I am changing base.xml I just can change "Edit" and "Create" buttons names, visibility based on form view name but I can't change anything what depends on form state. Maybe I don't know how. Now I am searching other ways to solve this problem. Thank you for your help @Michele Zaccheddu

Comment: If the *'state'* field belongs to the displayed model you can find it through *'widget.datarecord.< your state field name >'* and do your controls.

Comment: I eddited my main question and added piece of my form view xml code. In my form view I am using states which is written in my module. But I have no idea how to change base.xml that I can found the exact module state for exact view and hide base "Edit" button on exact view depend on module state.

Comment: Inside the *'widget'* object you have the *'datarecord'* object, which holds the fields belonging to the model displayed in the form view and their values. So you should be able to check it inside you *'t-if'* tag.

Comment: I tried to use like that:  <t t-if="widget.datarecord.state !== 'to_approve_first'">  some operations </t> but nothing. So hands down for a while. Do you try this 'datarecord' object? Maybe I have to set for it the module I don't know and I can't find.

Comment: Sorry the delay. I never used it in a template, but I did inside some widget and it should contain the fields and their values belonging to the view. So if you don't have that field in your view you should add it with the 'invisible' property set to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Using this you can inspect all the FormView widget fields, you can find it in */odoo/addons/web/static/src/js/views/form_view.js*.
I also found *datarecord* inside it, which should contain your *state* info and value.
Then, if you want to do the same with the buttons in *edit mode*, replace *'.o_form_buttons_view'* with *'.o_form_buttons_edit'*.

Tell me if you have problems. And again sorry for the delay, I was a little busy.

```
<t t-extend="FormView.buttons">
    <t t-jquery=".o_form_buttons_view" t-operation="before">
        <t t-log="widget"/>
    </t>
</t>
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. I have several solutions but no one is the best. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44000904/odoo-hide-edit-button-depend-on-state-and-group-role-javascript-formview

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! @Michele Zaccheddu using your answer I can get many types of the widget using

```
<t t-extend="FormView.buttons">
    <t t-jquery=".o_form_buttons_view" t-operation="before">
        <t t-log="widget"/>
    </t>
</t>
```

Just put the code as a test and after update apps - go to form view, check using browser Developer Tools, In the console you will get the list from "Class", I'm using odoo 11 and can target

```
<t t-if="widget.initialState.data.state === 'draft'">
```

For other versions, please check the t-log yourself it can be different, but I haven't check for user group it may or may not be there...